# Получение URl страницы при парсинге, без перехода по ссылке

Tags: python, html

Занимаюсь парсингом интернет-магазина. У каждой карточки товара есть ссылки которые ведут на фото. У одного товара может быть несколько фото, по этому ссылок может быть так же несколько. При парсинге приходится переходить по этим ссылкам и получать url через .find('meta').get('content').
В чём собственно заключается проблема, из-за того что на сайте стоит ограничение на количество запросов, парсинг url становится невозможным, выбивает ошибку об отсутствии на странице тега meta.
Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли получить url без перехода по ссылке?
Гиперссылка с текстом "Фото", переносит на другую страницу. С которого я и должен получить url.
[image: Первый скрин]

Comment: А вот куда вы переходите - это какой-то другой url, не тот который вам надо спарсить?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос скриншотом.

Comment: В самой гиперссылки url фотографии не указан